# How can I merge a list of vectors (in R) such that they have a minimum length?

Tags: r, merge

I have the following four vectors:

```
A <- c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5)
B <- c(6, 6, 6)
C <- c(7, 7, 7, 7)
D <- c(8, 8, 8, 8)
```

In the end, I'd like to transform this list of vectors (here 4 vectors) into **all pairwise combinations of full vectors (i.e. no splitting of individual vector)** with the **concatenated vector having a minimum length of 7**. One possible solution would thereby be:

```
s1 <- c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6)
s2 <- c(7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8)
```

How would I do that?

Comment: You shouldn't re-post the same question again. Improve the quality of your original question by editing and addressing the comments left by viewers.

Comment: @ Thank you for your comment. What is not clear? I tried to delete the old question, which obviously didn't work. But I think they should be merged now.

Comment: @ ycw. I see - will never ask something from my phone again. In the end, I'd like to transform a list of vectors (here 4 vectors) into a list of vectors (here 2 vectors, s1 and s2) having a minimum length of 7.

Comment: How should Patrick ask without being put on hold again? (I have a potential answer...)

Comment: Reopened here. The final edits on the ex-dupe suggested you wanted to find *all pairwise combinations* meeting the minimum length requirements. That was nice and clear, if it is an accurate description please edit it in here as well.

Comment: @CPak I think you can go ahead here, though it's still a little ambiguous whether the OP wants all combos or just one.

Comment: @ Frank. Only one combination. It doesn't matter to me which one (at least currently).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use `combn` to make pairwise combinations of your individual vector (ignoring direction `c(A,B) == c(B,A)` and self-concatenation, `c(A,A)` is not desired)

```
temp <- combn(list(A,B,C,D), 2)
threshold <- 7
L1 <- lapply(1:ncol(temp), function(x) Reduce("c", c(temp[1,x], temp[2,x])))
```

Discard concatenated vectors with length less than 7. I use `lengths` (note different from `length`) to grab length of all vectors in the list

```
L2 <- L1[lengths(L1) >= threshold]
```

#### Output

```
[[1]]
 [1] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6

[[2]]
 [1] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 7 7 7 7

[[3]]
 [1] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 8 8 8 8

[[4]]
[1] 6 6 6 7 7 7 7

[[5]]
[1] 6 6 6 8 8 8 8

[[6]]
[1] 7 7 7 7 8 8 8 8
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the extensive answer. This is actually exactly what I am looking for. Thank you so much for helping me! Great answer!

Comment: Glad to help. Hopefully you'll avoid using your phone next time ;)